# Can't connect to MySQL server on 'mysql.hostinger.in' (111 "Connection refused")

Tags: php, mysql, linux, host

I have this website where everything works great, but sometimes the following error is generated randomly while navigating around it:

```
Warning: mysqli_connect(): (HY000/2003): Can't connect to MySQL server on
'mysql.hostprovidername.com' (111 "Connection refused")
in /home/somepath/public_html/pagename.php on line 2
```

I cannot understand what the issue is. I have also talked to my host providers and they are asking for a particular url where they can see this error but the error is generated randomly at any time and on any page.

How can I give them any particular url?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a technical support issue specific to your hosting provider.

Answer (score 0):

Ask the Hosting provider about its reliability numbers. Chances are that when you cannot connect, the server might be actually down.